# Speed up strlen using SWAR in x86-64 assembly

Tags: strings, assembly, x86, simd

The asm function `strlen` receives the link to a string as a char - Array. To do so, the function may use [SWAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWAR) on general purpose register, but without using `xmm` registers or SSE instructions.

The function checks with the bit manipulation: `(v - 0x01010101) & ~(v & 0x80808080)`in 8 byte steps, whether the quadword contains a zero byte, which would mark the end of the string. If a zero is found, it iterates byte per byte up to the zero to avoid a page fault.

The alignment works like in this [GNU Libc implementation](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/string/strlen.c):

```c
for (char_ptr = str; ((unsigned long int) char_ptr & (sizeof (longword) - 1)) != 0; ++char_ptr){
    if (*char_ptr == '\0'){
        return char_ptr - str;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make it faster?

```
; rdi <- const *char
; rax <- counter + return value
; r10 <- current array for computation
; rcx,r8 <- Bitmask
; rsi <- Arr for calculation 
            
strlen:
    PUSH rbp
    SUB rsp,8
 
    XOR rax,rax    
    MOV r8,31
alignment:
    CMP byte [rdi+rax],0
    JE end
    
    MOV rsi,rdi
    ADD rsi,rax
    AND rsi,r8
    CMP rsi,0
    JE while_parallel
    INC rax
    JMP alignment       
          
while_parallel:  
    MOV rcx,0x01010101
    MOV r8,0x80808080
while_parallel_loop:  
    MOV r10,[rdi+rax]
    MOV rsi,r10
    
    NOT r10
    AND r10,r8
    SUB rsi,rcx
    AND rsi,r10
    
    CMP rsi,0
    JGE while_single
    ADD rax,8
    JMP while_parallel_loop
    
while_single:
    CMP byte [rdi+rax],0
    JE  end
    INC rax
    JMP while_single    
end:
    ADD rsp,8
    POP rbp
    RET
```

Note that I do not intend to use any SSE instructions nor `xmm` registers.

Comment: Did you have any unit tests?

Comment: no, I do not have any tests

Comment: "it iterates byte per byte up to the zero to avoid a page fault." The *byte per byte* is not going to avoid a page fault, because directly before it, the whole 8 bytes already have been read. So if a page fault could happen, it would happen while reading the quadword.

Comment: You can omit `PUSH rbp` `SUB rsp,8` ... `ADD rsp,8` `POP rbp` as they're not used. Will give a small speed gain on very short strings.

Comment: @SepRoland the way OP described it was wrong, but page fault are avoided through another technique: by aligning the address first

Comment: This was cross-posted from Stack Overflow, where njuffa posted a full working version with some optimization improvements, including using `bsf` on the bithack result. [Speed up strlen using SWAR in x86-64 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76401479) . (ping @harold).  I commented there with the suggestion of checking `(p  & 4095) <= (4096-8)` to allow an unaligned 8-byte load to start, instead of a byte-at-a-time loop until an alignment boundary, but haven't written an answer yet.  Handling the page-cross case with a load from `p & -4096` and a shift should also be possible.

Answer (score 7):

### A bug

Your constants are for the 32-bit version of the SWAR "has zero byte" trick, but you are processing 8 bytes at once. So the constants must be the 64-bit versions, which are the same pattern but twice as long:

```
MOV rcx, 0x0101010101010101
MOV r8, 0x8080808080808080
```

### Small missed opportunities

ALU operations in general set the flags according to their result, not just `cmp`. You don't always need `cmp`. For example after `AND rsi,r10` when we want to know whether `rsi` is zero or not, that information is already available in the zero flag, there's no need for `cmp rsi, 0`. Since the result of the `and` is no longer needed, it can be turned into a `test` (though that doesn't make it any faster)

Similarly, the check for alignment does not need a `cmp`. You can change the `and rsi, r8` to a `test rsi, 31` (but you should probably change the `31` as well, see below) and drop the `cmp`.

Zeroing a 64-bit register, such as `XOR rax, rax`, can be done by zeroing the corresponding 32-bit register, `xor eax, eax`. That often saves a byte, and [on some (low power) processors it is strictly better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33668295/555045). It's never worse, so you may as well.

A non-destructive addition, such as `MOV rsi,rdi \ ADD rsi,rax`, can usually be implemented with `lea`: `lea rsi, [rdi + rax]`. The advantage is small (thanks to move-elimination) and on many Intel processors this restricts the execution ports which the operation can be executed by, but on modern processors (Ice Lake and newer, Zen 3/4) `lea` (especially with only 2 parts in the address, and not `rip`-relative) is quite good.

If modern instructions are allowed, `not` and `and` can be merged into `andn`, which is non-destructive so you can also replace a `mov` with it:

```
MOV r10, [rdi+rax]
ANDN rsi, r10, r8
SUB r10, rcx
TEST rsi, r10
JNZ while_single
```

### Excessive alignment

The initial loop ensures that the address is aligned to a multiple of 32. That works, but you only need an alignment of 8 to make reading qwords from the string safe (in the sense of not triggering a page fault when the string ends nears a page boundary and the next page is not accessible). Over-aligning the address means that the slower byte-by-byte loops makes on average more iterations than it needs to.

### Loop pattern

Loops like this:

> ```
> while_parallel_loop:
>     ...
>     Jcc while_single
>     ADD rax,8
>     JMP while_parallel_loop
> while_single:
> ```

Can be rewritten into this form:

```
    JMP loop_entry     ; could use "sub rax, 8" in this case
while_parallel_loop:
    ADD rax, 8
loop_entry:
    ...
    Jcc while_parallel_loop    ; opposite condition
while_single:
```

### The `while_single` loop

The loop at the end, checking which of the 8 bytes within a qword (that is already known to contain a zero byte in it somewhere) is zero, can be replaced with a couple of instructions (without a loop) that find the index of the lowest set bit within the mask that was computed by the bithack, and then convert that bit-index into a byte-index, as shown in the answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: > "could use "sub rax, 8" in this case"
What do you mean by this?

Comment: @HeapUnderStop the `JMP` skips the `ADD` in this case. In general there might be something there that cannot be "cancelled out", but an addition can be cancelled out with a subtraction.

Comment: *The advantage is small (thanks to move-elimination)* - unless your code is bottlenecked on front-end throughput, then saving a uop for the front-end is exactly as good as you'd hope.  Also, Ice Lake disabled mov-elim for integer registers in a microcode update to work around an erratum, so once again, a significant fraction of CPUs don't have it, forcing tune=generic to make tradeoffs.  /sigh.  At least it was only Ice Lake, not Skylake. (SKL has other performance potholes from errata, though, some arguably worse like the JCC erratum, and a disabled LSD loop buffer being the other major one.)

Comment: `lea` is also good for flags elim; which probably isn't a problem in this code.